# upgrade form cassandra 1.2.5 to .1.2.6 failing

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster running on datastax-cassandra 1.2.5, it works fine, because of vnodes adn leveled compaction strategy issue i tried promoting it to 1.2.6.
So upgrading involved - 
1 - stopping all the nodes
2 - deleting 1.2.5 rpm 
3 - installing 1.2.6 rpm
4 - fixing cassandra.yaml
5 - starting cassandra.

**Problem Statement** - The problem now is that all the nodes are up and running, but not in one cluster. They all are operating in their own cluster even though the seeds in yaml points to the original seed.

- *nodetool status* also just shows the one node (the node on which we are on)
- system log shows one error

  ```
  ERROR [WRITE-/10.93.3.46] 2013-10-21 19:43:29,101 CassandraDaemon.java (line 192)            
  Exception in thread Thread[WRITE-/10.10.10.10,5,main]
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
          at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
          at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
          at          
  org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:351)
          at   
      org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:143)

  **** 10.10.10.10  is the seed ip
  ```

Any help on how to pass through it

Comment: Any good reason to down mark my question?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the internode_compression to none. It will disable compression between nodes, which is failing because snappy cannot initialize

internode_compression: none